# Riemann manifold isomorphic to $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

What is an example of a Riemann manifold which is not equal to $\mathbb C$ but it is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$?

I mean a manifold which doesn't have a group structure but it is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't have a group structure"?  You can always give it the group structure of $\mathbb C$.  That is, if $\phi: M \to \mathbb C$ is a biholomorphic map, define $a + b = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a) + \phi(b))$.

Comment: I mean for example in $\mathbb R$, we have a continuous bijective map from the interval $(1,2)$ to $\mathbb R$ where $(1,2)$ has no group structure. no?

Comment: @AmratA Of course $(1,2)$ has a group structure isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+)$. Namely, the one given by the operation $$x\oplus y=1+\frac1\pi\operatorname{arccot}\left(\cot(\pi x-\pi)+\cot(\pi y-\pi)\right)$$

Likewise for a product $\otimes$ such that $((1,2),\oplus,\otimes)\cong (\Bbb R,+,\cdot)$ as rings.

Comment: Well, for example, you can define a group structure on $(-1, 1)$ by $x \oplus y := \frac{x+y}{1+xy}$.  (This group happens to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ via the $\tanh$ function, which is also topologically a homeomorphism.)

Comment: So now for any group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H$, if $G/H$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$ then $H$ has to be normal in $G$?